# Formating a WKT CRS string in a way that R can read it

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, well-known-text, syntax

I have selected a custom CRS using the website https://projectionwizard.org/. I chose this custom CRS because I needed a map of the Neotropics (+ or - from the south of the US to the north of Argentina) that preserved distance. Now I have this WKT string and want to add it as the CRS of a raster object inside R. My problem is rather simple, I think: How can I provide R with this WKT in a way it can understand it and create a CRS object?

My custom WKT string is

> PROJCS["ProjWiz_Custom_Azimuthal_Equidistant",
> GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
> DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
> SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
> PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
> UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
> PROJECTION["Azimuthal_Equidistant"],
> PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
> PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
> PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-82.27],
> PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",-12.95],
> UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

When I do:

> `sf::st_crs(4326)$wkt`

It returns me this:

> `[1] "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"`

So I suppose the custom WKT string should be formatted in a way similar to this one (i.e., the WKT string for the WGS84 projection) for R to understand it, but I do not have the faintest idea how can I easily convert it from the format I have. I tried doing it by hand, but I do not understand the syntax very well to do so and it is quite cumbersome anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert it, its already in a format that `st_crs` understands.

With your string in an object named `proj`:

```
> proj
[1] "PROJCS[\"ProjWiz_Custom_Azimuthal_Equidistant\", GEOGCS[\"GCS_WGS_1984\", DATUM[\"D_WGS_1984\", SPHEROID[\"WGS_1984\",6378137.0,298.257223563]], PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0], UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]], PROJECTION[\"Azimuthal_Equidistant\"], PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",0.0], PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0], PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-82.27], PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",-12.95], UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]"
```

I can create a point at some lat-long roughly in the area you are interested in:

```
> pt = st_point(c(-90, 0))
> pts = st_sfc(pt, crs=4326)
```

and transform:

```
> st_transform(pts, st_crs(proj))
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -867785.2 ymin: 1423362 xmax: -867785.2 ymax: 1423362
Projected CRS: ProjWiz_Custom_Azimuthal_Equidistant
POINT (-867785.2 1423362)
```

You can also use `st_crs(proj)$wkt` to see how PROJ has re-interpreted your WKT into a form it seems to prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Spacedman! That did the trick!